# What "presents" is Grace referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, ready-or-not

In *Ready Or Not (2019)*, Alex Le Domas spoke to his fiancee Grace about brother Daniel
who warned Grace about their family, and hints that it's not too late to
flee. Daniel also mentioned to Grace that she doesn't belong in
their family:

> Alex Le: You know, Daniel's right. We could just... leave.
>
> Grace: Oh, sure, yeah. "Thanks for the **presents**. Go f*ck yourselves."
>
> Alex Le: No. I'm serious, I'm serious, honey.

What "presents" is Grace referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen the movie, but the words fiancee and flee tells me that they are getting ready to get married. I check the synopsis on IMDB and it is a movie about marriage. A quick answer to your question is the "presents" are gifts that you get when you get married.

The context of her statement is basically, and I'm paraphrasing:

1. We are about to get married
2. We have sent out the invites to all of our friends and family
3. Our friends and family have bought us gifts to help launch our lives as a married couple. Usually, these are nice, thoughtful, and sometimes pricey gifts. The word presents in this context is a synonym for gift
4. Today is the day to get married
5. Since I don't belong in the family, let's just leave the wedding but take the presents (i.e., gifts)
6. Doing this would be a huge FU to the wedding guests.